# The phrase ``set agoing''

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the use of the phrase ***set agoing*** legitimate? By *legitimate* I mean that if an author uses this phrase then her\his readers catch its meaning.

Incidentally, I have not found any evidence rejecting the hypothesis that the word ``agoing'' is not an established word.

Thanks so much beforehand!

Comment: some info here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111659/any-connection-between-akimbo-askance-and-atremble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, absence of contradiction isn't proof. If your claim is that *agoing* *is* an established word, then I can provide some evidence to refute it:

[GloWbE](http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/?c=glowbe&q=31828931), [CoCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=31828952) and [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=31828970) have less than 12 results between them, and all of them are stylistic variants of *going*.

Across over 1.9 billion words, there are just *eleven* examples of it.

There appears to be just one example of *set agoing*. I don't know what meaning you want to convey, but you probably want to *avoid* this construction, unless you're using it in some kind of narrative.

**In answer to your question**, though, yes, native speakers will probably understand your meaning if you mean "going", but they're likely to assume that it's a typo, or that you're mimicking someone with unusual speech characteristics.

---

Since you're asking for help on a language learners' site, I hope you won't mind me correcting other issues with your post:

- In English, we use the forward slash as a conjunction (/), not the backslash (\).
- Also, *thanks so much beforehand* isn't idiomatic. You may want to try *thanks so much **in advance*** instead.

Comment: By the way, one can only disprove rather than prove something outside mathematics; that is why I say `` I have not found any evidence rejecting the hypothesis that the word ``agoing'' is not an established word'' instead of simply ``The word `agoing' is not an established word''. The latter is an assertion, while the former is a hypothesis just passing a test of mine.

Comment: @Bri I think I must have misread the question, since I seemed to have it in my head that you were claiming _agoing_ was an established word.

Comment: I'm agoin' fishin' in the mornin'. -- I don't see the problem. Oh wait, yeah _set agoing_ I've never heard of.